# Want to post an iphone 4 video on youtube, but it needs to be rotated

Tags: iphone, video, photos.app, quicktime

I filmed something with my iphone 4 by rotating the phone so that it looks wide.  Like a widescreen TV.  But when I upload the .mov to youtube, the video is sideways and tall & skinny.  How do I rotate it?  Is there a setting in iPhoto or quicktime I can configure?  Or on youtube?

I'm surprised, Apple always makes things so easy... I would've imagined the camera software would recognize I started filming rotated and saved the picture as such...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Quicktime allows you some basic editing options such as Edit > Rotate
- iMovie allows more options such as cropping, rotate, trim, etc.

When you view your video in Quicktime is it in landscape format? If not, it's possible the phone was vertical (portrait) when the recording started. The camera should oriented either landscape or portrait ***before*** pressing record.

Comment: I very purposely put the camera horizontal when filming.  I'll try again.  I didn't see a save button in Quicktime initially, but then realized I just had to close the window after rotating and Quicktime will ask me to save it.  So that worked well.

Comment: If you pressed record, then turned it horizontal, it will still film vertical. It has to be oriented in the way you want before pressing record; that's really what I was trying to get across.

Comment: Yes ioi, I understood what you were saying.  My response was that I held the phone horizontal before filming...

Comment: I'm glad the QuickTime fix worked for you ~ take care.